# Find physical distance between two points from image using Python

Tags: python, math, image-processing, computer-vision, geometry

I have two coordinates (x, y) of an image

```
Point N: (x = 2314, y = 751), Width = 2880, Hight = 2304
Point S: (x = 1533, y = 670), Width = 2880, Hight = 2304
```

When I plot them in matplotlib they look like this. (Though there are some other points which also I plotted here.) -

[image: (Though there are some other points which also I plotted here.) -]

Now, I want to calculate the distance between `S and N`
I know The distance between x-ray plate and x-ray
the machine is 180 cm.

I already tried using the `math` function.

```
distance = math.sqrt( ((N[0]-S[0])**2)+((N[1]-S[1])**2) )
print(distance)
```

Which gives me results like this
`755.2747844327918`

But I need to know the distance (in meters). How can I do this in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have computed the distance in pixels.  You need to know the size of each pixel (eg, in mm), so you can convert it to mm by multiplying by a scale factor.

That scale factor is the product of 2 things:

1. the image sensor has physical dimensions that allow the size of each pixel to be calculated.  For example, if its active size is 288mm by 230.4mm and it produces an image of size 2880 x 2304 pixels, then the size of each pixel is 0.1mm.
2. most Xray machines can be approximated as a point source which illuminates the test subject, with the image plane behind.  Because it's a point source, the image projected on the image sensor is larger than the subject, with a scale factor determined by the relative distances between the source, subject and imaging plane. That will make the real distance smaller than the size projected on the imaging plane.  You can use geometry to compute that scale factor.  (Subtle point: unless the hardware or software already corrects for this, this actually isn't a uniform scaling across the image due to the fan-beam geometry.  So long as the subject is close to the imaging plane and the subtended angle is small, this factor will be close to 1.0 and, to first, order can be considered uniform across the image).

By combining those two factors you can convert your pixel distance into a subject physical distance.  Be aware if images are made with different distances between the source, subject and image plane then the 2nd scale factor will be different.

I'd recommend testing your calculation by putting a known-dimensioned object in the same plane as the test subject and measuring the resulting image.  You should also do it in both vertical and horizontal directions to make sure the pixels in the image sensor are square (which they should be).

Edit: is that a ruler in the top-right of the image?  Assuming it is, and it is in the plane of the subject, then use that to get the scale factor in one go!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice the ruler at first. And found that the ruler is 4.5 cm,
Then I calculated 4.5 cm in pixels which gives me 537.1126511263722 
1 Pixel means (4.5/537.1126511263722) cm. This is the Scale Factor I think.